# Returning last record in a subquery - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, greatest-n-per-group

So I am creating a messaging system similar to Facebook's style for my website (I know right). What I intend to happen is list all conversations for the user and also return the last message in the conversation. Problem is I am getting the first message when doing a GROUP BY. Perhaps I am going about it in the wrong way.

The structure of the database consists of three tables. ***conversations***, ***conversations_assign***, ***conversations_msg***

***conversations*** just stores the outside data of the conversation and the important thing is the id

***conversations_assign*** does just that. It lists the ***userid*** of everyone in the conversation

***conversations_msg*** stores obviously the message, user who posted with other data.

Everything is tied together with ***conversations.id*** = ***conv_id***

Here is the query I have and as I said from above with GROUP BY it is returning the first result. Taking off GROUP BY and adding LIMIT 1 literally returns one message and the rest are null. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
SELECT conversations.id,
    conversations_assign.num_unread,
    message
FROM conversations_assign
INNER JOIN conversations ON conversations_assign.conv_id=conversations.id                                     
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT conv_id, message, msg_time
    FROM conversations_msg
    GROUP BY conv_id
) AS message ON message.conv_id=conversations_assign.conv_id
WHERE conversations_assign.userid='XXsomeidXX'
ORDER BY message.msg_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with aggregation. Instead, you need to *filter*. If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend window functions:

```
select c.id, ca.num_unread, cm.message
from conversations_assign c
inner join conversations ca on ca.conv_id =c.id                                     
left join (
    select cm.*, rank() over(partition by conv_id order by msg_time desc) rn
    from conversations_msg cm
) as cm on cm.conv_id = ca.conv_id and cm.rn = 1
where ca.userid = 'xxsomeidxx'
order by cm.msg_time desc
```

In earlier versions, an alternative uses a correlated subquery to filter the `left join`:

```
select c.id, ca.num_unread, cm.message
from conversations_assign c
inner join conversations ca 
    on  ca.conv_id =c.id                                     
left join conversations_msg cm
    on  cm.conv_id = ca.conv_id 
    and cm.msg_time = (
        select max(cm1.msg_time) from conversations_msg cm1 where cm1.conv_id = ca.conv_id
    )
where ca.userid = 'xxsomeidxx'
order by cm.msg_time desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am not at this time.

Comment: I'm getting lost in the shorthand/abbreviations (especially in the left join), anyway you can fully write it out? Thanks for the response!